# Getting TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' for input numbers

Tags: python, typeerror

```
number = input ("enter a number : ")
if number > 10:
    print ("bigger than 10")
elif number < 10:
    print ("under 10")
```

How can I fix this error? I dont have any str:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: input return a string, cast with int() to get a "number" for example, number = int(number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing data between str and int.

By default `input()` returns string.

Solution:

```
number = int(input ("enter a number : ") )

if (number > 10): 
    print ("bigger than 10") 
elif (number < 10):
    print ("under 10")
```